# print(2 and 3) > 3 print(2 or 3) > 2

Tags: python, if, операторы, print

По какому принципу работают такие инструкции?

```
print(2 or 3) 
---> 2
print(2 and 3)
---> 3
```

Я хотел реализовать(2 равно 3-ке или 2-ке)

```
print(2 == (3 or 2))
```

но она работает не так как мне надо... Выдает False, а я жду True.

Comment: *Выдает False, а я жду True.* Ой, долго ждать будете.  А пока ждёте - почитайте про [логические операции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Вкратце
    
    or : возвращает первый приводимый к True результат, а
    and: проверяет оба на истинность, возвращает последний проверямый

Comment: А ваше сравнение как-то : `print(2 in [3,2])`  или
        `print((2 == 3) or (2 ==2))`

Comment: Akina, точно)) по таблице логических операций сверился)))

Comment: splash58, со списком отличный вариант, спасибо!